# Find what's consuming .bss using gcc or binutils

Tags: gcc, memory, embedded, binutils

Is there a tool gcc or binutils that can show me the big consumers of .bss? I have tried to sum up sizes from `objdump -t bin-file | grep bss` but it does not add up to the same as when I do `size bin-file`.

I am trying to find out where the ram is going in an embedded project that is using some external libraries.

[EDIT]
It turned out to be the heap section defined in the link script that ate the "extra" bss that I did not see.

Comment: Do you generate a .map file ? Because that's where I would look for the symbols present in .bss. However I don't know if the libraries' symbols will be there.

Comment: Yes, but I did not know what to use it for. It looks like what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Print BSS consumption of every object file:

```
size --common -t *.o
```